# How to improve the syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, codeblocks

The code I wrote appears to have a couple of syntax mistakes, yet code blocks doesnt show them. Instead of running the program it opens the ios_base.h and shows a few errors there.

Error message:

> ```
> error: 'std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits˛& std::basic_streambuf>_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_streambuf>_CharT, _Traits>&) [with_CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is private
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h|789|error: 'std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)' is private| C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h|66|error: within this context|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\streambuf|810|error: 'std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is private| C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\fstream|72|error: within this context|
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct artikl()
{
    int sif;
    int kolic;
    char naz[20];
    float cena;
};
void unos()
{
    fstream myfile;
    myfile = fstream("file.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    artikl art_val;
    cout << "Unesite sifru: ";
    cin>>art_val.sif;
    cout << "Unesite kolicinu: ";
    cin>>art_val.kolic;
    cout << "Unesite naziv:  ";
    cin>>art_val.naz;
    cout << "Unesite cijenu:  ";
    cin>>art_val.cena;
    myfile.write((char *) &art_val, sizeof(artikl));

    myfile.close();
}
void ispis()
{
    fstream myfile;
    myfile = fstream("file.bin", ios::in | ios::binary );
    artikl art_val;
    myfile.read((char *) &art_val, sizeof(artikl));
    cout << "Naziv:  " << art_val.naz << "\n" << "Sifra: " << art_val.sif << "\n" << "Cijena: " << art_val.cena << "\n" << "Kolicina: "<< art_val.kolic << "\n";
}
int main()
{


    cout << "Izbornik: \n" << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        cout<< "1. Unos podataka: \n";
        cout<< "2. Ispis: \n";
        cout<< "9. Izlaz iz programa \n";
        int a;
        cin>>a;
        if (a == 1)
        {
            cout<<"Unesi podatke koje treba upisati u datoteku.\n";
            unos();
        }
        else if (a == 2)
        {
            cout<<"Podaci iz datoteke su: \n";
            ispis();
        }
        else if (a == 9)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            cout<<"Niste unijeli 1, 2 ili 9.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you look at the note from the compiler below the bunch of errors, it tells you the line in your program that's wrong. You can't assign file streams.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. What do you propose to improve it?

Comment: Get used to constructing the object you want instead of default-constructing an object and then immediately overwriting it. Include your constructor arguments in your declaration. Do `foo x(bar);` instead of `foo x; x = foo(bar);`.

Comment: I did, the same thing happens..

Comment: Make a switch(a){case 1: <statement> case 2: <statement> case 9: <statement> } out of the if/else if/else

Comment: Tried it, gives the same errors again..

Comment: A [mre] might help. Remove all the code that's irrelevant to the problem and post the smallest example that can be used to reproduce the problem as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a default constructed `fstream` object, then immediately trying to assign another new `fstream` object to it, which is not allowed.

You should just combine the two statements into

```
fstream myfile("file.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Comment: I've tried it, the same happens only with a different error in ios_base.h

Comment: @holdup Did you make that change in all of your functions?

Comment: I have, do you think it might be something else too?

Comment: Errors:
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h|789|error: 'std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)' is private|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h|66|error: within this context|

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\streambuf|810|error: 'std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is private|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\fstream|72|error: within this context|

Comment: Code is the same apart from that alteration

Comment: You sure you saved the changes and you're compiling the right file? Compiles fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/-nA7fY

Comment: The error message says that you cannot use operator= on a stream. You say that you've fixed that error. Maybe we could progress if you posted your new (fixed) code.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I'm new to this.. Here is the fixed code. 
void ispis()
void unos()
{
    fstream myfile("file.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    artikl art_val;
    cout << "Unesite sifru: ";
    cin>>art_val.sif;
    cout << "Unesite kolicinu: ";
    cin>>art_val.kolic;
    cout << "Unesite naziv:  ";
    cin>>art_val.naz;
    cout << "Unesite cijenu:  ";
    cin>>art_val.cena;
    myfile.write((char *) &art_val, sizeof(artikl));

    myfile.close();
}

Comment: void ispis()
{
    fstream myfile("file.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    artikl art_val;
    myfile.read((char *) &art_val, sizeof(artikl));
    cout << "Naziv:  " << art_val.naz << "\n" << "Sifra: " << art_val.sif << "\n" << "Cijena: " << art_val.cena << "\n" << "Kolicina: "<< art_val.kolic << "\n";
}

Comment: @BessieTheCow It does run online, however I need it to run in codeblocks.

Comment: @holdup What is the error message you get with the fixed code?

Comment: Please edit it into the question so you can format it properly.

Comment: error: "x" is private
error: within this context
error: "x" is private
error: within this context

Comment: @holdup I can see no occurance of the identifier "x" in either the code in the question or the updated code in the comments. And please don't put code in comments it's impossible to read, please **edit the question** instead.

Comment: @holdup I suspect that code blocks is still compiling your old code. In other words you have made some sort of mistake in trying to update your code. Best thing to do is probably delete everything and recreate the work you've already done. Second time around everything will work fine.

Comment: @holdup As I said (and others have too) that's an error I would expect from your old code. And as you have said the code now compiles correctly in a online compiler. Therefore I think you've got yourself confused somehow with code blocks. Maybe you are editting a different file from the one that code blocks is actually compiling. I don't think there's a real problem here, just some mistake you've made in using code blocks.

Comment: @john closing codeblocks and opening a new project fixed it, thank you